# Behaviour of positive frequency solutions for Dirac equation under a boost (Peskin 3.52)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, inertial-frames, dirac-equation

In Peskin and Schroeder, when discussing about the positive frequency solutions of Dirac equation,  it has been derived a form for $u(p)$ as shown in equation (3.50) (page 46):
$u(p)=
\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{p\sigma} \xi \\ \sqrt{p\bar\sigma}\xi 
\end{pmatrix}$, where $\textbf{p}$ can be directed along any direction.
Later on P&S apply this relation to the spinor $\xi = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ (spin up along the 3-axis) and obtain (3.52):
$u(p)=
\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt{E-p^3} \begin{pmatrix}1\\0 \end{pmatrix} \\ \sqrt{E+p^3}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0 \end{pmatrix} 
\end{pmatrix}$ without pointing out if $\textbf{p}$ is directed alongside the 3-direction or not.

Now my question is, does the transformation shown in (3.52) work only for a situation in which $p=p^3$ or is it more general? If it is indeed general where does that come from?

Comment: Hey! are you reading the text sentence by sentence missing out their strategy laid out at the bottom of p 45, where they've boosted to the $p^3$ frame? You may rotate it to  any direction that the rotational invariant $\sigma \cdot p$ allows, which they give to remind you of their $p^3$ frames essential generality! Of course it's for that frame. Of course you may perform a rotation to generalize it, but that's not what they are teaching you there...

Comment: Thanks for the answer! No I had understood that the strategy was to start from the rest frame and then boost to generalize the results; I was simply unsure of that expression in 3.52! Thanks for helping me clarify it.